# Can the attribute of an entity in a database assume a "yes" or "no" value?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

The main question is in the title of the topic.
Let's say i have an entity called for example : "room"
Every room has an "Unique number",is on a certain "floor" and has a number of "beds"(Those are clearly attributes).
If i want to know if a room is also "for smokers or not" and if it has the "space for an additional bed or not", can i consider those as attributes with just a "yes" or "no" value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly.  An attribute is defined as a mapping from an entity set (e.g. rooms) to a value set (e.g. yes/no, numbers, names, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much.
another question if possible. The room has also a bathroom with a bathtub,a shower or both
Can i represent "bathroom" as a subentity and "bathtub" and "shower" as specialization with a total overlapping even if bathroom,bathtub and shower have no attributes at all?